# Can I display pictures outside backend web folder in yii2?

Tags: yii2

I have a little problem. I can’t view images outside the backend web folder.

Aliases in common\config\main:

```
 'aliases' => [
    '@upload' => dirname(dirname(__DIR__)).'/upload',
 ],
```

View Dataprovider:

```
 [
   'format' => 'raw',
   'label' => 'Immagine',
   'value' => function ($data) {
       return Html::img(Yii::getAlias('@upload') . $data->codice_prodotto . '/' . $data->immagine, ['width' => '70px', 'class' => 'img-thumbnail']);
    },
 ],
```

Can I resolve? Thanks.

Comment: what url do you get from ```Yii::getAlias('@upload') . $data->codice_prodotto . '/' . $data->immagine``` ?

Comment: or you can use something like this ```yii\helpers\Url::to(['@backend/web/upload'])```

Answer (score 1):

If your file is not accessible for http server, so you can't directly download it.

**You can:**

- Move uploads directory to directory accessible for the http-server
- Create action that will read the file from private directory and stream it to the browser (you can use yii\web\Response::sendFile() function for that)

**Streaming file to the browser**

Please read this official docs article to understand this deeply: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-response#sendFile()-detail

**Action code example for your case:** *

```
public function actionFile($filename)
{
    $storagePath = Yii::getAlias('@upload');

    // check filename for allowed chars (do not allow ../ to avoid security issue: downloading arbitrary files)
    if (!preg_match('/^[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z0-9]+$/i', $filename) || !is_file("$storagePath/$filename")) {
        throw new \yii\web\NotFoundHttpException('The file does not exists.');
    }
    return Yii::$app->response->sendFile("$storagePath/$filename", $filename);
}
```

**And view Dataprovider configuration:** *

```
[
   'format' => 'raw',
   'label' => 'Immagine',
   'value' => function ($data) {
       return Html::img(Url::to(['/path/to-streaming-action/file', 'filename' => $data->codice_prodotto . '/' . $data->immagine]), ['width' => '70px', 'class' => 'img-thumbnail']);
    },
 ],
```

** Notice that this code is not ready to copy-paste, please read it carefully and try to understand the principle before implement it in your code.*

Comment: Simple solution might also be creating a symlink to upload folder where it will be accessible directly e.g. in `backend/web`.